# Retry http request with Angular Interceptor ONLY when user clicks a button

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-http-interceptors, rxjs-pipeable-operators, angular-errorhandler

I'm using Angular HttpInterceptor to handle errors in my Http requests.

If there is an error other than 401, I am displaying a popup modal that contains 2 buttons ('Close' to close the modal and 'Retry' to retry their request again).

However, I am having trouble figuring out how to retry the http call when the user clicks the 'Retry' button. I have confirmed that the console log displays when the user clicks the 'Retry' button, but I'm not sure how to make the http request again. Would I need to clone the request first?

Here is my InterceptorService:

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpErrorResponse, HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from "rxjs/operators";
import { AuthService } from '@auth0/auth0-angular';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
import Swal from 'sweetalert2'
import { NgxSpinnerService } from 'ngx-spinner';

@Injectable()
export class InterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document,
    public auth: AuthService,
    public spinner: NgxSpinnerService,
  ) { }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    return next.handle(request)
      .pipe(
        catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          let errorMsg = '';
          // logs user out if unauthorized, this works fine.
          if (error.status === 401) {
            errorMsg = 'Unauthorized';
            this.auth.logout({
              returnTo: this.document.location.origin
            });
          } else {
            errorMsg = `Error Code: ${error.status},  Message: ${error.message}`;
            Swal.fire({
              text: `Error Encountered!`,
              confirmButtonText: 'Retry',
              confirmButtonColor: '#0f172a',
              cancelButtonText: 'Close',
              cancelButtonColor: '#f87171',
              showConfirmButton: true,
              showCancelButton: true
            }).then((result) => {
              if (result.isConfirmed) {
                // I want to retry the http request here. The console log is working fine.
                console.log('User has clicked retry button, should retry http request again...');
              }
            });
          }

          return throwError(() => error);
        })
      );
  }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
    retry(request: HttpRequest<any>): Observable<any> {
      return this.http.request(request.method, request.url, {body: request.body, params: request.params, headers: request.headers});
   }
```

and then you can just return in your if statement

```
     if (result.isConfirmed) {
        this.retry(request).subscribe();
     }
```

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately

Comment: I realized that the retry method returns a observable, and you are calling it in your popup. So the subscribe method is never triggered. Try adding subscribe to the end of retry. IE:
this.retry(request).subscribe()